# How can I achieve this sound? (Wolfgang Gartner - Fire Power)

Tags: effect

Hey everyone, my question relates to a specific sound heard in Wolfgang Gartner's "Fire Power"

[youtube]7M7CiegyP90[/youtube]

It's the sound at 1:25 to 1:26, here it is sampled:

http://audioboo.fm/boos/604605-sample

It's also heard in "VDE 128BPM Economic Melody Root A"

http://audioboo.fm/boos/604615-sample2

Does anybody here know how to re-create this sound, and could help out? I'd really appreciate it.

I'm using Live.

Looking forward to any replies, thanks a lot in advance.
-V.

Answer (score 3):

That sound is (probably) a VST Instrument or synth. From the sounds of it, it could have been created from the Nord Lead 3. A similar sound (but obviously higher pitch) is present as the main lead on [Yeah Yeah by Bodyrox feat. Luciana](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Xq4q1wCk4), which was created with the Nord Lead 3. Take a look [here](http://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/the-40-greatest-synth-sounds-of-all-time-ever-306114/40) for how that was created.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Haha, I was going to post almost the exact same. It sounds like a Nord Lead indeed, though you could probably make it with any VA Softsynth. And the Bodyrox lead sprung to mind as well, which a friend of mine recreated 1:1 on his Nord.

Comment: Hehe, great minds... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's an arpeggio or step-sequensing of an subtractive synth (based in filters and pitch). The Nord Lead-line is good at this, though it actually can be a heavily processed Moog (my best guess: MiniMoog or Little Fatty) or KORG MS-20 too!

Good bite on that one :-)